# I keep getting NoSuchElement exception in my Java code. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, fibonacci, nosuchelementexception

My Java 1.7 program performs various mathematical functions. I have separated the functions into methods and they work ok on their own. I also made a prompt method that asks the users if they want to continue. However, I keep on getting NoSuchElement exception after inputting a number. "Try again? (n/y) " prints, but it doesn't wait for user input and errors automatically. Eclipse Luna highlights this line:

```
String response = scanner.next();
```

Here's the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Please input a number: ");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(chooseOperation(x));
        do_Continue();
        if (do_Continue() == false) {
            break;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Here's the operation chooser method:

```
public static int chooseOperation(int n) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Factorial, Fibonacci, or Pisano? ");
    String response = scanner.next();
    scanner.close();
    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("factorial")) {
        return factorial(n);
    } else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("fibonacci")) {
        return fibonacci(n);
    } else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("pisano")) {
        return pisano(n);
    } else {
        System.out.print("Invalid response. ");
        chooseOperation(n);
        return n;
    }
}
```

And here's the prompt method:

```
public static boolean do_Continue() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Try again? (n/y): ");
    String response = scanner.next();
    scanner.close();
    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        return false;
    } else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.print("Invalid response. ");
        do_Continue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

If this helps, here are the methods for the math functions:

```
public static int factorial(int n) {
    if (n==1 || n==0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}

public static int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n==1 || n==0) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
    }
}

public static int pisano(int n) {
    if (n==1 || n==0) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)) % 7;
    }
}
```

As you can see, except for the main method, all my methods are recursive.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Is all that code relevant? Why post it if it isn't? Have you done the necessary debugging to find where there error is? What line does your exception stack trace point to?

Comment: I don't know which code might be of use to you. If you take a look at the top, I stated that Eclipse Luna highlights "String response = scanner.next()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call

```
scanner.close();
```

When you do that, you `close()` `System.in`! Then when you attempt to construct your `new Scanner(System.in);` it doesn't work (because `System.in` is closed).

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño Make sure you remove all of those calls. I see several. You can open multiple Scanner(s) on System.in (or just pass the same Scanner to your method(s)).

Comment: @ElliotFrisch It works, but "Try again? (n/y)" prints twice and only at the second response will the main method reiterate. Also, it doesn't print out "Invalid response"

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño What is the value of `response`? Also, do you know to use the [debugger](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html)? Don't forget to call `System.out.flush();`

Comment: @ElliotFrisch response has the value of whatever I type, either correct or incorrect. If I type "n", response is "n"; If I type "u" response is "u".

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño Don't recurse in `do_Continue` after `System.out.print("Invalid response. ");`.

Comment: EDIT: I removed the first do_Continue in the main method, leaving the do_Continue in the conditions of the if statement.